# Hypergeometric Function

Tags: reference-request, hypergeometric-function

I am reading about algebraic differential equations and I would need some more recent refferences on the subject, especially something detailing the work of Schwarz and Klein starting with the hyergeometric function:
$$z(z-1)F''(z)+[(a+ b +1)z-c]F'(z)+abF(z)=0,$$
Most articles cite Introduction to the Theory of Linear Differential Equations by EGC Poole or Ordinary Differential Equations by Ince. I would like, if possible, some more recent books since I find both of these a bit hard to follow.

Comment: What do you want to know about specifically?

Comment: The proofs for obtaining the Schwarz list.